# presentModalViewController not showing search in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm tying to pop up a modal UITableView with a search bar to allow the user to select an item.  This is displayed from the flipside of an app created using the Utility template.  I can display the UITableView fine, but although I can add a Search Bar and Search Display Controller component onto the the table in IB fine, when run the search is not displayed when the modal view is poped up.

Is this possible?  Is there some restriction on using modal views with search?

EDIT: I got around this by changing the flipside view to use a navcontroller and showing the UITableView by pushing that rather than modal.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?

Also, what about having the modal view load the search view (a view within a view). That seems like a work around if indeed it is not standard behavior.